# In Android develop, how to implement a click on one certain region of the background?

Tags: android, view, click

I am programming in Android and now I want to add a function in my app which is to response a click of one certain region of my background without no feedback of any kind.

I am doing an app as a gift to my girlfriend and I want to give her a surprise when she clicks somewhere. To be a surprise, it is not supposed to be a button, a text or a picture, but only somewhere normal as other regions of the background.

I know maybe I can insert a picture which is the same pattern as background, but are there some smarter methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a button that's transparent.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```